# Display SQL JOINED table in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have added `LIMIT 3` in below code to display 3 results of a JOINED table. However in Python multiple lines was displayed. In SQL execution, it is fine.

Please advise what is the reason? THanks

```
lib = cur.execute('''SELECT Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name
  FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist
  ON Track.genre_id = Genre.ID AND Track.album_id = Album.id
  AND Album.artist_id = Artist.id
  ORDER BY Artist.name  LIMIT 3''')
for row in lib:
  print(row)
```

[image: SQL]

[image: Python]

Comment: Check [PEP-249 DB-API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) for `cursor` object: *execute(operation [, parameters]): Return values are not defined.*. You should remove `limit` and use `fetchmany(3)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to :

```
 cur.execute('''SELECT Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name
  FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist
  ON Track.genre_id = Genre.ID AND Track.album_id = Album.id
  AND Album.artist_id = Artist.id
  ORDER BY Artist.name  LIMIT 3''')
lib = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Hi, the result displayed is still multiple rows. not 3 rows.